# Asynchronous request processing in Spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have written  a servlet to handle the asynchronous requests. After calling  `request.startAsync(req,res)` I am storing the asyncontext for further processing ie putting some information in a queue which is being polled by some other thread. When I try to flush the stream from the servlet response is not getting committed to the client.

```
@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/async" }, asyncSupported = true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final long                        CONNECTION_TIME     = (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            System.out.println(task+"Inside servlet  > " +request.isAsyncStarted() );
            request.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
            final AsyncContext oAsyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);
            oAsyncContext.setTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME);

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            message.setConnectionObject(oAsyncContext);
            oAsyncContext.addListener(new AsyncClassListener(userid, oAsyncContext));
            //oAsyncContext.complete();



            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(("trying to respond"));

            out.flush();
            System.out.println(out.checkError()+"flushed" +response.isCommitted()+response.getStatus());


    }

}
```

Comment: If you're using Spring, then why are you dealing with low-level constructs like servlets?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async). Spring can handle this out-of-box with minimal configuration.

Comment: I believe you should call `complete()` after print and flush. And if you are using spring, then you better create a proper service and return a Future class